# How to filter a virtual tree

Tags: qooxdoo

Has there been any updates to this post (How to filter a virtual tree...)?

http://qooxdoo.678.n2.nabble.com/How-to-filter-a-virtual-tree-td7050674.html

Comment: I guess I could try to emulate this: https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/master/application/demobrowser/source/class/demobrowser/DemoBrowser.js  I love the DemoBrowser tree filter!

Comment: This is not a good question for SO. You shouldn't just post a link to some mailing list and ask for progress here. Question should be properly formulated. It would also be nice to stick to one channel for a question, rather than cross-posting. That makes it hard to follow for everybody.

Comment: @ThomasH Sorry about that, I'm not sure where the nabble feed comes from, but I see it a lot on google searches for qx related queries. I figured this was the best place to post the question since it's a Q&A site. Where would be the better place?

Comment: The Nabble feed is an archive of the qooxdoo mailing list (just go to the main page, qooxdoo.678.n2.nabble.com). It contains many conversations over many years, so it's natural to come up high on searches. So either join the qooxdoo mailing list for your own questions, or use SO. But in the latter case make some effort to (re)formulate the question for the SO audience, so SO readers have enough information to make sense out of it (see the FAQ).

Comment: @ThomasH Thanks for the clarification! I will be more diligent about this in the future. Again, my apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this issue is already fixed and will be part of the upcoming 2.1 release: 
https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/commit/92d6494c35cf1270f2b7ce5fcdd47fe9be21fb02